# Delphi 5 reading tdate as 64bit integer

Tags: delphi-5

I am using my trusty old **Delphi 5** and struggling with the following problem.

I am trying to interpret a Truetype/opentype font creation date by reading it directly from the font file.

The [spec](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/head.htm) has the following description:

Format **LONGDATETIME** which is Number of seconds since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 
1904. 64-bit integer

I am creating an array of word to read this structure with the following:

```
longDateTime = array[0..3] of Word;
```

I can read and correctly interpret other data from the **head** table in the font file correctly but not the timedate value.

I am aware of the swapped words issues.

One font has date **06/08/1990** and time **14:54:50**
The hex dump in the file is `00 00 00 00 A2 E3 27 2A`

Can anybody please help/explain how I can get above date/time from this hex dump?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `Int64`? It is available in D5: `longDateTime = Int64;`

Answer (score 2):

there is a little timezonedifference

```
Var
 C:Cardinal=$00000000A2E3272A;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 d:TDateTime;
begin
  d := Encodedate(1904,1,1) + c / 24/60/60 ;
  Showmessage(DateTimeToStr(d));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks bummi but why 1904,1,1 ?
Will this correction work for all Opentype / truetype font dates?

Comment: The value retreived from the font is relative to Jan 1 1904.  That is why `EncodeDate(1904,1,1)` is being used. `TDateTime` is a floating point value, so bummi is converting the font value into a floating point value that expresses the same value in seconds, and then adding that the `TDateTime` that `EncodeDate()` returns (D5 does not have the `IncSecond()` function that was introduced in D6, which would accomplish the same thing). Another way to write it would be: `d := EncodeDate(1904,1,1) + (c / SysUtils.SecsPerDay);`

Comment: Problem solved !!
Many thanks for all your valuable input. I have a much better understanding of Date Time issues
Many many thanks
Neil